# sqlalchemy Integer column size

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I saw somewhere that you can define a column size for Integer columns (e.g. Integer(20), Integer(10), etc.) but for some reason, it seems that sqlalchemy ignore those sizes in the create table query it produces through create_all():

```
class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = "t_job"

    id = Column(Integer(20), Sequence('%s_id_seq' % __tablename__), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(30))
    company_id = Column(Integer(20), ForeignKey("t_company.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
```

Produces the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE t_job (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(30),
        company_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES t_company (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

If that's not a proper way to do this, what is?

Comment: Also the size on integers in MySQL is *mostly* pointless. I'd just use Integer. See http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/

Answer (score 10):

This functionality was [deprecated in version 0.7](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_07.html).

If you are using MySQL, you can use the `mysql.INTEGER` datatype:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql 

class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = "t_job"

    id = Column(mysql.INTEGER(20), Sequence('%s_id_seq' % __tablename__), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(30))
    company_id = Column(Integer(20), ForeignKey("t_company.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
```

Comment: That does misses the point of using an ORM, doesn't it? (I need to support Oracle also)

Comment: From what I have seen, when one uses the mysql.INTEGER type and connects to a non-mysql database the type reverts to the built in Integer type, so Oracle should still work. I don't think Oracle's INTEGER allows the size to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

There are no arbitrary size integers but SQLAlchemy supports besides `Integer` also `BigInteger` and `SmallInteger`.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#generic-types