# Commiting objects with long integers to MYSQL with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, long-integer

I am trying to add a large integer to a `MySQL` table with `SQLAlchemy`. As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804920/2327821) explains, you cannot pass `Integer` a length argument like you can `String`. So following that answer I've defined my column with `mysql.INTEGER` like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
uniqueid = Column(mysql.INTEGER(20))
```

When I try to commit an object with a 14 digit uniqueid, however, I get the following error message: `DataError: (DataError) (1264, "Out of range value for column 'uniqueid' at row 1")`. When I try a shorter integer that is not a long, it has no problem committing the same object to the SQL database. I am running python 2.7, other [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16820639/2327821) of the `long` type indicate that it should not behave any differently than `int` except for printing an `L` at the end of the number. One final piece of information is if I set the uniqueid to the same short number but make it a long, as in `uniqueid = long(32423)`, I can still commit the object to the SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not solve the mystery of why the `mysql.INTEGER` class will not work with numbers that have to be `long` in python 2.7, but the practical solution is to use `SQLalchemy`'s `BigInteger` class, which as the name suggests can handle big integers, including `long`.